# Extending a ActiveRecord class from a rails Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-engines

I have a rails app which uses a ActiveRecord model defined in a rails engine.  I want to add some methods to that class (in this case FormInstance), so I simply use the syntax:

```
class FormInstance
  def mynewmethod
    #..my code here..
  end
end
```

But this doesn't seem to work.  It does indeed create FormInstance class with the new method, but it's not extending the Engine class, all the original methods of the FormInstance class are gone.  What's the correct way to do this?

Env: rail 3.2.13, ruby 2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the decorator pattern.  There are multiple ways of implementing it.  Have a look at the activesupport-decorators gem.  It hooks into Rails ActiveSupport and adds a convention to doing decorators that is safe from circular dependencies.  We have been using it in production on multiple apps for a while.

https://github.com/EPI-USE-Labs/activesupport-decorators